# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Param1' not found

Tags: r

I read train_data from csv and then train GBM model as follows:

```
train_rows <- sample(nrow(train_data), round(nrow(train_data) * 0.5))
traindf <- data[train_rows, ]
testdf <- data[-train_rows, ]

gbm_formula <- as.formula("traindf$myTarget ~ Param1 + Param2 + Param3")
gbm_model <- gbm(gbm_formula, 
                 traindf, 
                 distribution = "bernoulli", 
                 n.trees = 200, 
                 bag.fraction = 0.75, 
                 cv.folds = 5, 
                 interaction.depth = 3)
```

Then I get the following error appears:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Param1' not found
```

The only solution that I know is to specify `gbm_formula` as follows:

```
gbm_formula <- as.formula("traindf$myTarget ~ traindf$Param1 + traindf$Param2 + traindf$Param3")
```

Is there another solution to fix this?

Comment: Does it work if you change your formula to: `gbm_formula <- as.formula("myTarget ~ Param1 + Param2 + Param3")`

Comment: @eipi10: No,then it says "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'myTarget' not found". I really don't get the point, because all the tutorials that I've seen use this formula. But it does not run for my data. I double-checked that the column names are correct.

Comment: Try changing `traindf` to `data=traindf` in your call to `gbm`. I think you need to name the argument, since the second-position argument in the function is actually `distribution`.

Comment: @eipi10: Now it says again about the Param1

Comment: Well, now I'm stumped. Can you post a small sample of your data frame along with the output of `str(traindf)`?

Comment: @eipi10: Actually, your solution was right: data=traindf There was one small bug. After fixing it, your solution solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Since that solved your issue, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `traindf` to `data=traindf` in your call to `gbm`. You need to name the argument, since the second-position argument in the function is actually `distribution`.

You can also change the formula to `as.formula("myTarget ~ Param1 + Param2 + Param3")` (though that wasn't the cause of the error).

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
gbm_formula <- as.formula(paste0("myTarget~",paste0("Param",1:3,collapse="+")))
>gbm_formula
myTarget ~ Param1 + Param2 + Param3
```

Comment: ? this shows how to make a formula, not how to address the question

Comment: Without reproducible example, I can't help much to the OP. This is why I use `may` .